# jqPlot: define chart parameters from json

Tags: json, jqplot

I'm trying to figure out if is it possible to configure a chart from json file and how to do it.

Let's write the sentence in another flavour: can I use a json file to pass jqPlot both the data to plot and the chart parameters?

Till now I just used json file to store data.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance,
Evan

Answer (score 0):

You can, here's an example using an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'input.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(options) 
    {                                   
        var data = [
        [3, 7, 9, 1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 5],
        [4, 8, 10, 2, 5, 7, 9, 3, 6],
        [5, 9, 11, 3, 6, 8, 10, 4, 7],
        [6, 10, 12, 4, 7, 9, 11, 5, 8],
        [7, 11, 13, 5, 8, 10, 12, 6, 9]];

        var plot = $.jqplot('chart', data, options);                
    },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
    alert(textStatus)
  }
});
```

Here the chart options are retrieved from a (in this case) local JSON file, it looks like this:

```
{
"legend": {        
    "show": true,
    "placement": "outsideGrid",
    "location": "s",
    "rendererOptions": {
        "numberRows": 1
    }
},
"seriesDefaults": {
    "showMarker": false,
    "fill": false
}}
```

Then the plot is generated as usual. One limitation (I believe): if you want to use a custom renderer (such as $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer) you can't specify that through JSON.

Comment: Thanks Kryptic, but one thing is still not clear: is input.json containing the options?
In this case, should I write:
    var plot = $.jqplot('chart', data, url); ?
Where do I pass the json chart options?

Comment: @EBAH yes, input.json contains the options. the options are the returned data from the ajax request (the variable "options" in the success function), and that's what you pass to jqplot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the rest of you, but I didn't like the response here and was determined to make this work.  I was successful finally, and it works with things like "$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer" without any problem.

In my case I'm actually passing things from a CherryPy application, and I needed to be able to pass the options as JSON along with the data for the chart.  I ended up just passing the entire options set as a string, and then using EVAL to change it back into javascript code.  Once I figured out the syntax it actually works perfectly.  Here's the best way to make it work.

1) Figure out all your options without using any JSON, to make sure the plot actually works properly.
2) Copy the options argument for jqPlot verbatim.
3) Make sure to add parenthesis around the options so that EVAL will evaluate it properly, otherwise you will get an syntax error.
4) Encase this whole thing into a string type object on the server side.
5) This will then go through JSON.dumps as it's returned to the client with the rest of your data.
6) On the client javascript just do an EVAL on the object that was returned, and set the result to your options argument.

Here's an example:
As you can see here I'm also making calls to the data renderer within the options.  As long as the options are called within an appropriate context on the client, it will evaluate all the variables, etc. just fine and works perfectly.  This is working in jQuery 1.11.0, with jqPlot 1.0.8r1250.

Server object:

```
options = """({
        dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
        dataRendererOptions: {
            name: name
        },
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                label:xLabel,
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions:{formatString:'%R'}
            },
            yaxis:{
                tickOptions:{
                    formatString:'%.0f'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            placement: 'outsideGrid',
            labels: seriesLabels,
            location: 'ne',
            rowSpacing: '0px'
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true,
            zoom:true
        }
    })"""
```

Return to client:

```
output = json.dumps({
                     'name': name,
                     'xLabel': header[0],
                     'seriesLabels': header[1:],
                     'parms': parms,
                     'options': options,
                     'parmData': parmData,
                     'successful': True
                     })
```

Javascript:

```
var options = eval(incomingData.options);
var plot = $.jqplot('chart_'+name, "/getChartData", options);
```